# Castear UIImagePicker de video a Data en Swift

Tags: swift

Hola tengo un pequeño código en donde obtengo un video del carrete del teléfono a código, y ahora necesito transformar ese video a la clase Data para a si poder enviarlo por un Rest service, ¿alguien sabe alguna manera?

```
        var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    private func cargar() {
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary

    imagePicker.mediaTypes = ["public.movie"]
    self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: {

    })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Pásalo usando la url del video, declara primero una variable de tipo Data:

```
          var dataVideo = Data()

          guard let url = URL(string: "videoUrl") else { return }
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
           print(data)    // -> te imprime los datos del video, checa como obtener la url del picker
         dataVideo = data

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.userInfo)
    }
```

Esa seria una forma, otra es usando ReadingOptions:

```
       guard let url = URL(string: "videoUrl") else { return }

    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url, options: .mappedIfSafe)
            print(data)
            dataVideo = data
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.userInfo)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Presento la solución tomando como ejemplo el comentario de @Yan Cervantes, agregue una extensión en donde se obtiene la url, y agregue un signo de ! al string en las url.

```
extension MiClaseController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

// Esta funcion se llama despues de haber seleccionado el video
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? URL
    print("videoURL:\(String(describing: videoURL!))")


    var dataVideo = Data()

    guard let url = URL(string: "\(String(describing: videoURL!))") else { return }
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        print("Data : >>>  \(data)")    // -> te imprime los datos del video, checa como obtener la url del picker
        dataVideo = data
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.userInfo)
    }

    /*guard let url = URL(string: "\(String(describing: videoURL))") else { return }
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url, options: .mappedIfSafe)
        print(data)
        dataVideo = data
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.userInfo)
    }*/


}
```

}

Comment: Bien!, yo te recomiendo que en donde se desempaqueta la url "en donde colocaste la expresión , ! , "  lo hagas de manera segura, en vez de poner videoURL! antes del print coloca - guard let url = videoURL else { return } y en vez de poner el videoURL coloca la variable url.

Comment: tal como lo haces antes del "do"